# Select a row in GridView with RadioButton

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, radio-button

I have a page that contains a GridView with a LinkButton, in a template column, that selects a row.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Selecionar" CommandArgumento='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>
```

How can I do this with a RadioButton? I'd like so that when a user selects the radiobutton, my grid would execute the RowCommandEvent. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Edits

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Height="30px">
<ItemTemplate>

<%-- It works with a linkbutton -->
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelecionar" runat="server" Text="Selecionar" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' Visible="true"></asp:LinkButton>

<%-- i need a RadioButton =/  --%>
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioRole" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="Role" />

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: CommandArgumento ? Is that Portugese?

Comment: Yes, I wrote wrong, I'm sorry!

Comment: Aha, what we did was rebuilding the readibutton to a custom control and implement the CommandEvent and the Commandargument, via the IButtonControl and the IPostBackEventHandler interfaces ;)

Comment: ahaha, is there another solution more simplest? hehe.. .maybe some javascript to do something necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ImageButton` control instead. Use a radiobutton selected or unselected image as the `ImageUrl` and since the button click is creating postbacks, set the correct `ImageUrl` of the button that is clicked. You get all the features of a button with the look of a radiobutton.

-- Worth a try

**Edit**

I worked up some sample code. There are two images. radioButtonOn.gif and radioButtonOFF.gif. Here are the important parts:

Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    OnRowCommand="gvItems_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/radioButtonOFF.gif" CommandName="ibtnRadio" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Item" DataField="Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
 protected void gvItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "ibtnRadio")
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridViewRow gvr = gvItems.Rows[rowIndex];
        ImageButton ib = gvr.Cells[0].Controls[0] as ImageButton;
        if (ib != null)
        {
            ib.ImageUrl = "~/radioButtonOn.gif";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Dave, do you have some sample to show? Any article on web? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @DaveB, I solve my problem with checkboxes, doing a foreach loop do uncheck others checkbox isn't in the CurrentRow. But I'll stydu your solution! Thanks!